# ros noetic from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, ros

I have Ubuntu 20.04.4 and I want to ask you a question.
I have ros noetic & gazebo.If I upgrade my system to 22.04, will there be any problem ?
Is ros noetic compatible with 22.04 ?

Thanks.

Comment: I believe that the only "safe" way to keep software is to 1a. uninstall it, 1b. upgrade, then 1c. reinstall  OR 2a. do a clean install, 2b. install that software again. Backup your data in either case.

Answer (score 1):

ROS Noetic will be the last ROS1 version and it will only support Ubuntu 20.04. So, the answer is yes, there will be a problem, as 22.04 is not compatible.

This information comes from the official Docs. The following link provides additional information.
https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#noetic-ninjemys-may-2020-may-2025

2 alternatives:

- Now, you may compile ROS in 22.04 and there are people that have done
  just that, with success. I don't have any link at the moment, but
  you'll find a few online easily.
- On the other hand, if the performance overhead is not an issue, you
  may use Docker to run ROS Noetic on 22.04 (or any other host system).
  This is the approach I personally use. In my environment, performance
  overhead is not an issue even running video applications in an
  embedded system.

Comment: A link is never a good answer. You can have the link for reference but if there is something in that link that is the answer it needs to be in the body of the answer. Cut and paste works well.

Comment: My statement is the answer. The link is official Documentation that supports it.

Answer (score 0):

A year of time seems to have changed things.

There is now a “ros-core” package, and related dev packages, included in ubuntu 22. It is ros1.

interestingly the ros distribution name is not “noetic” but “Debian”

Edit: discovered there are currently a few "missing pieces" though:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ros-metapackages/+bug/2037302

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).